# Call method in class from another class in C#

Tags: c#, methods, call

I have a small problem when I'm trying to call method from another class (not Main class). Here's my testing code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 cl = new Class1();
            cl.TestMethod();
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string TestMethod()
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }

    public class Class2
    {
        Class1 cl = new Class1();
        cl.TestMethod(); //Error here
    }
}
```

What should I do to call TestMethod in Class2?

Answer (score 3):

You can't call methods into class body. Specify method or, for example, put your code into a `Class2` constructor like below:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 cl = new Class1();
            cl.TestMethod();
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string TestMethod()
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }

    public class Class2
    {
        Class1 cl = new Class1();

        public Class2()
        {
            cl.TestMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a method from outside a method,constrcutor or a property 
change class two to this:

```
public class Class2
{
    public Class2
    {
       Class1 cl = new Class1();
       cl.TestMethod(); //Error here
    }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have classes confused with methods.

A method is a subroutine, a bit of code that can be invoked from otjer parts of the code and runs sequentially.

A class is a data type. You create specific instances of a class and then access its properties or call its methods.

So Main is a method, not a class. Specifically it is a method of the program class.

In a class, all executable code must be inside a method. The one (sort of) exception to this rule is that you can initialize members outside of a method. That's what you did with `c1 = new Class1()`. These statements are implicitly executed when you create the class with new.

To invoke the class1 method you have to either declare a method on class2 to do it.l, or define a constructor which inokes it. However it is very bad practice to have a constructor that does a lot of work. A construct should only do things like initialize members which are required for the class to function.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a second class, which needs a method, or constructor inside it in order for this to work. Wrap it around the instantiation and it will be accessible :)

Answer (score 0):

class is by default body is private and private access modify Rules : Not assign value in private variable and use only method other class method is pubic but use this class is private then you not access this object to method

Answer (score -1):

There is a simle solution. Just as you do it with Math.Abs();
You should use **static** method,

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Class1 cl = new Class1();
            cl.TestMethod();
            C_Auxilary.F_TestMeth();   
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        public string TestMethod()
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }

    public class Class2
    {
        Class1 cl = new Class1();
        cl.TestMethod(); //Error here
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public static class C_Auxilary
    {
        public static void F_TestMeth()
        {
            ;
        }
    }
}
```